# Error after typing a command to clear npm cache ```sudo npm cache clean -f```

Tags: node.js, caching, npm, terminal

I'm currently using Linux mint:
After running `sudo npm cache clean -f` in terminal, I have now a problem with the npm cache. here is the text Error:

```
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path /home/mint/.npm/_cacache/tmp/15c7b348
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Your cache folder contains root-owned files, due to a bug in
npm ERR! previous versions of npm which has since been addressed.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! To permanently fix this problem, please run:
npm ERR!   sudo chown -R 999:999 "/home/mint/.npm"

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/mint/.npm/_logs/2019-11-25T05_52_58_726Z-debug.log
```

Can someone help me to fix this problem ? Even with the solution proposed in terminal, I don't know how to handle it.
Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

I found myself ;) 
Just run this command on the terminal: sudo chown -R 999:999 "/home/mint/.npm"